# Trackbars do not work using python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to control the threshold of a video capture using a group of trackbars for the HSV of each frame captured here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
h_Min=0
h_Max=256
s_Min=0
s_Max=256
v_Min=0
v_Max=256
Frame_Width=640
Frame_Hight=480
Max_DetObj=50
Min_ObjArea=40*40
Max_ObjArea=Frame_Width*Frame_Hight/1.5
def nothing(x):
    pass

def Trackbars():
    cv2.namedWindow('Trackbars',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.createTrackbar('H_Min','Trackbars',h_Min,h_Max,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('H_Max','Trackbars',h_Max,h_Max,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('S_Min','Trackbars',s_Min,s_Max,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('S_Max','Trackbars',s_Max,s_Max,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('V_Min','Trackbars',v_Min,v_Max,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('V_Max','Trackbars',v_Max,v_Max,nothing)
def Pics():
calibMod=True
if(calibMod):
    Trackbars()
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
retVal, frame = vc.read();

while True :
    if frame is not None:
        hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        if (calibMod==True):
            #ret,threshold=cv2.threshold(hsv,0,255,0)
            hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            threshold=cv2.inRange(hsv,(h_Min,s_Min,v_Min),(h_Max,s_Max,v_Max))
            morphop(threshold)
            cv2.imshow('threshold image',threshold)
            trackObj(threshold,hsv,frame)
        cv2.imshow('camera',frame)
        #cv2.imshow('threshold',threshold)
        cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
   rval, frame = vc.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

the probleme is that none of the trackbars is working and when i change it's values nothing change on the window of threshold
what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either need to supply a *valid* callback function ( your nothing() does, well, .. not much .. )

or query the value explicitly:

```
 if (calibMod==True):
     #ret,threshold=cv2.threshold(hsv,0,255,0)

     hue_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('H_Min','Trackbars')
     hue_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('H_Max','Trackbars')
     sat_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('S_Min','Trackbars')
     sat_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('S_Max','Trackbars')
     val_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('V_Min','Trackbars')
     val_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('V_Max','Trackbars')

     hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
     threshold=cv2.inRange(hsv,(hue_min,sat_min,val_min),(hue_max,sat_max,val_max))
     ...
```

Comment: @ berak you mean put {H_Min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('H_Min','Trackbars')} instead of {h_Min=0}? and if so should i do it also with {h_Max}?

Comment: oh, sorry, typo. no i meant the trackbar value instead, H_min,h_Max  are the bounds (see edit).

Comment: @ berak thank you it works but it is to heavy it takes to much time to change the image ,any ideas about the reasons?!